# Nodejs - data download and saving in chunks

Tags: javascript, node.js, blob, fetch-api

### What I am trying to do

I am fetching an image from a website with `node-fetch`, and I'm saving it to disk. My question is if I can save that image in chunks rather than downloading *all* of the image, and then saving *all* of the downloaded data at once. Doesn't seem like that node way to do things.

### `node-fetch` documentation on how to save images

```js
fetch('https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png')
    .then(res => {
        const dest = fs.createWriteStream('./octocat.png');
        res.body.pipe(dest);
    });
```

That results in a 0 byte big image, on closer inspection `res.body.pipe()` is undefined, but doesn't throw an error ?

### What I currently have

After a bit of investigation I noticed that the "downloaded" data is in a blob form. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) says that I should "process"(?) that blob with `arrayBuffer` and then I can save that buffer to disk with `.write`.

```js
 const result = await (await (await fetch(url)).blob()).arrayBuffer();
 const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('./1.jpg').write(Buffer.from(result));
```

This setup "works", but the saving nor the downloading of the file is not done in chunks, everything is basically synchronous. I feel like I am missing something or I am doing something wrong.